# Intuition or Motivation behind definition of Homomorphism - Fraleigh p. 29

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, intuition

> p.29: A **binary algebraic structure** is a set $S$ together with a binary operation $*$ on $S$ and is denoted $<S, *>$
>
> p.29: Let $<S,*>$ and $<S',*'>$ be binary algebraic structures.
> An **isomorphism** of $S$ with $S'$ is a function $\phi$ mapping $S$ onto $S'$ such that
> $1. \, \phi$  is one-to-one.
> $2. \, \phi$ is onto.
> $3. \, \phi$ satisfies the **homomorphism** property: $\phi(x*y) = \phi(x) *' \phi(y)$ for all $x, y \in S$.

What's the intuition or motivation behind the homomorphism property? Everything is from p. 29 Section 3 hence before groups, subgroups, ... are introduced.

I thought an isomorphism is a bijective linear transformation? How is a homomorphism related to a linear transformation : $T(a\mathbf{v} + b\mathbf{w}) = aT(\mathbf{v}) + bT(\mathbf{w})$, for all scalars $a,b$ and vectors $\mathbf{v,w}$ ?

**Update Dec. 24, 2013** dezign wrote "a homomorphism is a function between sets which respects some sort of algebraic structure on the sets ". But how does this lead to $\phi(x*y) = \phi(x) *' \phi(y)$? Still looks weird.  Wikipedia's paragraph on intuition doesn't explain it. It just does some examples.

Comment: The conditions 1) and 2) guarantee that $S$ and $S'$ are 'about
the same' as sets. If they are satisfied then $S$ and $S'$ are isomorphic
as sets. Conditions 1), 2) and 3) guarantee that $\left(S,\star\right)$
and $\left(S',\star'\right)$ are 'about the same' as binary algebraic
structures. If they are satisfied then $\left(S,\star\right)$ and
$\left(S',\star'\right)$ are isomorphic as binary algebraic structures. You could say that 3) (homomorphism) takes care of the structure. I have added the tag 'categories'.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphism etc.

Comment: @drhab: Thanks. Do you want to Answer with that? I can upvote it.

Comment: See also http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NaturalProjection.html.

Answer (score 3):

In some approaches, such as Fraleigh's, it is natural to define isomorphisms before homomorphisms so that one can identify structures that look different but are really the same. This then leads to homomorphisms by relaxing the requirements of injectiveness and surjectiveness, leaving just the important property of preserving structure, in the sense of preserving corresponding operations.

A bijective linear transformation is an isomorphism of vector spaces. A homomorphism of vector spaces is just a linear transformation, which need be neither injective nor surjective.

Answer (score 1):

In general, a homomorphism is a function between sets which respects some sort of algebraic structure on the sets (the appropriate language here is category theory, but we'll just stick to the basics). In the example you mentioned, a linear transformation respects the vector space structure of a vector space, i.e., you can perform the vector space operations before or after you apply the function, and you still get the same thing. Then this property may be generalized to a set with some sort of binary operation, i.e.,  the property that you can perform the binary operation before or after you apply the function and you still get the same thing. Functions with this property are called "homomorphisms".

Comment: Thanks and upvoted. Can you look at my update please?

Comment: Doesn't my answer precisely address your update?  Also, another useful thing is that homomorphisms always send 0 to 0. This is particularly useful when studying when something is zero. For example let's say you want to prove that a polynomial has no root over the integers, then you can do this by just finding an integer $n$ such that the polynomial has no root after reducing its coefficients modulo $n$, as the map $\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}_n$ given by reduction modulo $n$ is a homomorphism. So if the polynomial had a root over $\mathbb{Z}$ it must have a root over $\mathbb{Z}_n$.

Comment: Thanks. I updated my question to answer this. What should I look for in your answer for the update?

Answer (score 0):

The conditions 1) and 2) guarantee that $S$  and $S′$   are 'about the same' as sets. If they are satisfied then $S$  and $S′$   are isomorphic as sets. Conditions 1), 2) and 3) guarantee that $(S,⋆)$  and $(S′ ,⋆′ )$  are 'about the same' as binary algebraic structures. If they are satisfied then $(S,⋆)$  and $(S′ ,⋆′)$  are isomorphic as binary algebraic structures. You could say that 3) (homomorphism) takes care of the structure. I have added the tag 'categories'.